# grid component in materia ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I have this code and I get this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & SystemProps<Theme> & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<GridClasses>; ... 14 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: Element; item: true; lg: 4; mmd: number; md: 3; ssm: number; sm: 4; key: string; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; item: true; lg: 4; mmd: number; md: 3; ssm: number; sm: 4; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<GridClasses>; ... 14 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'mmd' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<GridClasses>; ... 14 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.ts(2769)
OverridableComponent.d.ts(17, 7): 'component' is declared here.
```

```js
<Grid
    item
    lg={4}
    mmd={4}
    md={3}
    ssm={6}
    sm={4}
    key={`col${item.id}`}
>
```

Why does this error happen?

Comment: Can you add a bit more of your code to the code snippet? There should be a <Grid container> around the <Grid item>, please include that bit too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why this happen. Because I use mmd in grid its not recognized